# What is wrong with this proof of $A\times B \subset C\times D$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A, B, C, D$ be finite sets with $A\subset C$ and $B\subset D$. What is wrong with the following **incorrect** proof that $A\times B\subset C\times D$?

**Proof**: Since $A\subset C$ we have that $|A|\le |C|$. Since $B\subset D$ we have that $|B|\le |D|$.

We know that $|A\times B|=|A| \times |B|$ and $|C\times D|=|C|\times |D|$. So $|A\times B| = |A|\times |B| \le |C|\times |D| = |C\times D|$.

Since the cardinality of $A\times B$ is less that the cardinality of $C\times D$, we must have that $A\times B$ is a subset of $C\times D$.

Comment: A proof that **never** uses the hypothesis that $A\subseteq C$. What could possibly be wrong with that?

Comment: Honestly I don't know and I'm very confused. Can you explain please

Comment: Here are two sets: $\{0\}$ and $\{1,2\}$. The cardinality of the first is less than the cardinality of the second. But the first is not a subset of the second.

Comment: Hint: An optimal proof of this fact will not mention cardinality at all.

Comment: "What is wrong with the proof?" The "we must have" in the last sentence is a non sequitur, as explained in the first comment by @halrankard2 .

Comment: But in the case of the incorrect proof, A is a subset of C so eg A={1} and C={1,2}, so A is both a subset of C and has a lower cardinality? Sorry if I'm sounding stupid but I'm new to this sort of maths and it's quite confusing to me.

Comment: @ibibat You're on the right track. The point is exactly that your "proof" doesn't *really* use $A\subseteq C$, only $|A|\leq|C|$. So you need to rewrite your proof so that it *really uses* the definition of $A\subseteq C$ involving elements of sets. You shouldn't even need to refer to cardinality at all to prove this fact.

Comment: @halrankard2 thank you. This proof isn't actually my method, it's a question about a deliberate incorrect proof. So if I wanted to correct it, would I have to use A⊆C by for example giving examples for what A and C could be?

Comment: @ibibat I don't follow what you say. You are trying to prove a general statement about all sets, so a "correct proof" isn't going to be done via examples. On the other hand, if you are looking for examples that show why the wrong proof is wrong, then I have already indicated how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Cardinality inequalities do not imply that one set is a subset of the other, but only that there is an injection from the smaller set to the larger. So the proof is invalid because it does not, and cannot, show $A×B\subseteq C×D$ from $|A×B|\le|C×D|$.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite your proof to focus on set containment, and not cardinality.

You want to show $A\times B\subseteq C\times D$. So work from the definitions. This means that you need to show that *every* element of $A\times B$ is an element of $C\times D$. So fix an arbitrary element of $A\times B$. What does it look like? Show that this element is in $C\times D$ using the *assumptions* $A\subseteq C$ and $B\subseteq D$.